# DocumentDb Spatial Distance in Linq returns weird result

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

When I do a documentdb linq distance query on two Points (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial) that are the same I get different results.

Below test returns a List containing one LocationDocument. test2 returns returns an empty list. The isEqual bool returns true though, so I cant understand why they return different results. I have manual confirmation that the longitude and latitude are the same also.

```
// one document
var test = MyCollectionRepository<LocationDocument>
           .GetItems(x => x.Point.Distance(x.Point) < radius)
           .ToList();   

// no documents
var test2 = MyCollectionRepository<LocationDocumentDocument>
            .GetItems(x => x.Point.Distance(point) < radius)
            .ToList();

// true
bool isEqual = point.Equals(test[0].Point);
```

Here is the GetItems() method called from the repository:

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetItems(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var items = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink)
        .Where(predicate)
        .ToList();
    return items;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Its not the easiest thing to debug since the Distance calls are only available when run as a query in documentdb.

Thanks in advance.

Point Object:

```
point.Position.Latitude.ToString(); //18.4239
test[0].Point.Position.Latitude.ToString(); //18.4239

point.Position.Longitude.ToString(); //-33.9253
test[0].Position.Longitude.ToString(); //-33.9253
```

**Edited:**

I have updated to the latest version of the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB library (1.4.1) and the problem has changed. As mentioned in the comments the issue seems to be with my CultureInfo settings. I am on a non-US culture (en-ZA to be precise).

test2 was then throwing an exception, while test1 was still outputting the expected result. I was getting an AggregateException. I then just had to add the enable scan in query to the header. Below is how you do that:

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetItems(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var items = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink, new FeedOptions { EnableScanInQuery = true })
        .Where(predicate)
        .ToList();
    return items;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem with this data. Can you please include the value of radius. Activity IDs will also help.

Comment: This is due to a bug in the DocumentDB SDK in building LINQ to SQL queries in non EN locale settings: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-net/issues/49. Fix coming shortly.

Comment: we believe we have fixed this issue but would like to confirm. are you able to provide a repro project? are you running with a CultureInfo other than en-US or even en-ZA (as I see you're from Kaapstad)

Comment: we have published 1.4.1 of the .NET SDK. could you please check and see if this resolves your issue.

please report back here. Thx.

Comment: @RyanCrawCour-MSFT Thank you for the update. Yes im using the en-ZA cultureInfo (Cape town indeed :) ). The problem has changed now. I will edit the question to reflect the change.

Comment: @RyanCrawCour-MSFT It's working like a charm now! Thank you for responding over here. Really benefited from your MVA course btw.. keep it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug (now fixed) in the DocumentDB SDK in building LINQ to SQL queries in non EN locale settings: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-net/issues/49.

Comment: Good point. That could very well be it. Unfortunately Point doesnt have a .ToString() but I edited to include the doubles. The other thing is that I know for a fact that the distance between test[0].Point and point is smaller than the radius (The points are the same floating values) so I cant understand why its not returning the points in that radius. I think i must be fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier correct me if I am wrong, it does answer the question. we stated the problem is due to a bug in the SDK.